# Display content below background image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On my home page I have a full width background image, however, my content won't display below it. Rather, it is displaying over top of the background image. Can anyone help me make my content display below my background image?

This is my html code:

```html
<html>
<title>PLR.com Home</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.homepage-backgroundimage {
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
 background-size: cover;
 left:0; right:0; top:0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
 }

.flexcontainer-bodyarea {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #bbb;
 }
.flexitem-50ptextarea {
 width: 480px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 }
    
body {   
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #bbb;
  }
</style>


<body>
<div class="homepage-backgroundimage"><img src="http://pianolessonresource.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Untitled-1.jpg"></div>
<div class="flexcontainer-bodyarea">
  <div class="flexitem-50ptextarea">This is one text area</div>
  <div class="flexitem-50ptextarea">This is two text area</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot display your text below the background image, that way you won't be able to see it. Although you can put transparent background to your divs.

Comment: The background container is positioned absolute. That might be what is causing your problem. Try relative and then you will have to play with the background sizing I am guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Make it  a *real*  background image (in the CSS rule, not in an image tag), remove the absolute position for that DIV and give it 100% height:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.homepage-backgroundimage {
  background: url(http://pianolessonresource.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Untitled-1.jpg) center, center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.flexcontainer-bodyarea {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.flexitem-50ptextarea {
  width: 480px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage-backgroundimage"></div>
<div class="flexcontainer-bodyarea">
  <div class="flexitem-50ptextarea">This is one text area</div>
  <div class="flexitem-50ptextarea">This is two text area</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code seems to work perfectly here, but when I put it into my website it doesn't. This leads me to believe there must be an issue with some of my other code.

Comment: Did you add 100% height to `html` and `body` as shown in my code example? Also, if there are any other elements *between*  `body` and `.homepage-backgroundimage` (i.e. parent elements of `.homepage-backgroundimage`), these also need a `height` defiinition of 100% for this to work.

Comment: Yes, I've added the height to my code and it looks fine... But, I still have <style> in my code before it... is this an issue? The image just isn't displaying at all anymore... Can't figure out why!

Answer (score 0):

Put `position:relative` instead of `position:absolute`

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<title>PLR.com Home</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.homepage-backgroundimage {
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    left:0; right:0; top:0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    }

.flexcontainer-bodyarea {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    }
.flexitem-50ptextarea {
    width: 480px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    }

body {   
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #bbb;
  }
</style>


<body>
<div class="homepage-backgroundimage"><img src="http://pianolessonresource.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Untitled-1.jpg"></div>
<div class="flexcontainer-bodyarea">
  <div class="flexitem-50ptextarea">This is one text area</div>
  <div class="flexitem-50ptextarea">This is two text area</div>
</div>
```